# Can a subdomain website create more subdomains on the same parent domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, subdomain

I am creating a rails website which needs the ability to create subdomains, however, the admin panel which can create these subdomains needs to also be located on its own subdomain so that the parent domain is separate.

Is it possible to create subdomains from a website already on a subdomain?

Sorry if it's hard to understand, I struggled to explain it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have just one application responding to how many domains you want. Just need to user proxy_pass if you are using nginx

Check this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass